# Problem trimming Japanese string in java

Tags: java, string, nlp

I have the following string (japanese) "　ユーザー名" , the first character is "like" whitespace but its number in unicode is 12288, so if I do "　ユーザー名".trim() I get the same string (trim doesn't work).
If i do trim in c++ it works ok.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue in java?
Is there a special trim method for unicode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to the `StringUtils` class mentioned by Mike, you can also use a Unicode-aware regular expression, using only Java's own libraries:

```
"　ユーザー名".replaceAll("\\p{Z}", "")
```

Or, to really only trim, and not remove whitespace inside the string:

```
"　ユーザ ー名 ".replaceAll("(^\\p{Z}+|\\p{Z}+$)", "")
```

Comment: this will also replace the white character in the middle of the string

Comment: Be warned that regular expressions are *much* slower than the standard trim() method. If performance is a problem (or becomes one), it would probably be worth your time to write your own trim() without the regex. At the very least, use a compiled Pattern to do the replaceAll().

Comment: hmm, not generalizable to other languages.  I much prefer the ICU4J method.

Comment: Phil, I'm not sure I understand your comment, why is it not generalizable to other languages? It should work for all Unicode whitespace.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wish I could upvote this 10 times.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Unicode Normalization](http://www.unicode.org/charts/normalization/index.html) and the [Normalizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class. The class is new in Java 6, but you'll find an equivalent version in the [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/) library if you're on an earlier JRE.

```
    int character = 12288;
    char[] ch = Character.toChars(character);
    String input = new String(ch);
    String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFKC);

    System.out.println("Hex value:\t" + Integer.toHexString(character));
    System.out.println("Trimmed length           :\t"
            + input.trim().length());
    System.out.println("Normalized trimmed length:\t"
            + normalized.trim().length());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the Apache Commons' [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class. The StringUtils.strip() method should work for you.

Comment: this doesnt really work for Japanese space character.

Answer (score 2):

From the java docs, it explains why this doesn't work.

> If this String object represents an
>   empty character sequence, or the first
>   and last characters of character
>   sequence represented by this String
>   object both have codes greater than
>   '\u0020' (the space character), then a
>   reference to this String object is
>   returned.

You could role your own version easily enough. perhaps the method codePointAt could be used for this purpose.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to write your own `trim()` method based on `Character.isWhitespace()` - unfortunately, `trim()` does not do what its API doc claims: it strips only ASCII spaces, not any other kind of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simple way to trim Japanese string in java

```
public static int getTrimmedLength(CharSequence s) {
    int len = s.length();

    int start = 0;
    while (start < len && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(start))) {
        start++;
    }

    int end = len;
    while (end > start && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(end - 1))) {
        end--;
    }

    return end - start;
}

public static String trimWhitespace(CharSequence s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    while (sb.length() > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(0))) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    }

    while (sb.length() > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1))) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```